# Python: I'm trying to find the maximum difference between two elements in a list

Tags: python

I need to find the maximum difference in a list between any two elements. In list `[1,2,3,4,5]` the maximum difference is  4 (between elements 1 and 5) using for loops.

This program needs to output the location of these two elements (0 and 4) and their values (1 and 5).

I can only figure out how to find the max difference between consecutive values, but this creates a problem if the maximum starts elsewhere, e.g. `[4,1,6,3,10,8]` where the largest difference is between 1 and 10 (positions 1 and 4). Can someone help me?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I must use either for loops to accomplish this

Comment: Think about the two elements of the list that have the maximum distance between them. Is there anything else "special" about them with respect to the rest of the list?

Comment: Please don't add clarification in comments; edit the original question.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the built-in functions `max` and `min` to find the maximum and minimum values respectively and then use the list method `index` to find their indices in the list.

```
numlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

max_val = max(numlist)
min_val = min(numlist)

max_pos = numlist.index(max_val)
min_pos = numlist.index(min_val)
```

Comment: That should be 'numlist' instead of 'maxlist' in line 2 and 3.Again in line 4 and 5 instead of just 'list'. Also your answer is just perfect for the question and should be accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In the naive approach, you simply have two nested loops in that makes sure that each elements visits every other list element. As you only need to check every pair once, it’s enough to start the inner loop at the *next* index every time:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

max_i, max_j = None, None # stores the indexes
max_d = -1 # stores the maximum distance we have seen so far

# iterate through all indexes of the list
for i in range(len(lst)):
    # iterate through all indexes, but starting from the index `i+1`
    for j in range(i + 1, len(lst)):
        d = abs(lst[i] - lst[j])
        if d > max_d:
            # memorize everything if the distance is larger than what we know
            max_i, max_j, max_d = i, j, abs(d)

print(max_i, max_j, max_d) # 0 4 4
```

With two nested loops, this is of course not really efficient, but this is essentially the solution for when you *really* need to compare every list element with each other. In your case of finding the maximum distance, as others pointed out, you only need to look at the largest and the smallest list item which can both be determined in linear time.

---

As you said in a comment above, it seems that you are only allowed to use for loops, so we can still make it efficient, by doing the min/max finding ourself in linear time, by iterating only once:

```
# set the current maximum and minimum to the first index
max_i, min_i = 0, 0

# iterate the list from the second index
for i in range(1, len(lst)):
    # check if we’re larger than the current maximum
    if lst[i] > lst[max_i]:
        max_i = i

    # check if we’re smaller than the current minimum
    if lst[i] < lst[min_i]:
        min_i = i

distance = lst[max_i] - lst[min_i]
print(min_i, max_i, distance) # 0 0 4
```

This essentially does the same as the answer by mgilson does. We just do the job of built-in functions `max` and `min` ourselves and find the minimum and maximum manually.

Answer (score 3):

You can *sort* the list first, then get the minimum and maximum values. Also, use `index()` to get the position of an element:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

temp = sorted(L) # sorted list

min = temp[0]
max = temp[-1] # index -1 will give the last element
```

**Test:**

```
print "min", min, L.index(min)
print "max", max, L.index(max)
print "difference", max - min
```

**Output:**

```
min 1 0
max 5 4
difference 4
```

Comment: Calling sorted changes this from an O(n), constant memory problem to an O(n log n), O(n log n) memory one. It's *massively* inefficient.

Comment: @arshajii min, max, and mapping those values to indices are all O(n).

Comment: @arshajii -- I've posted an O(n) solution, so did Alex Thornton (although without the indices)

Comment: @mgilson Yes, misunderstood the problem. My apologies.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann it's a list of 5 small numbers, the language is Python. I can't see efficiency is of all that much concern here. :P

Comment: It may be inefficient, but it is an intuitive solution to the problem, that works fine for small problems, and shows how to use sorted and negative indices.

Comment: While the O(n lg n) bound on time complexity is correct, the space complexity is at worst O(n), and for many algorithms is O(1).

Comment: @chepner sorry, the space complexity was a mistake on my end. O(n) is right.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler That's a slippery slope you're on, and it leads to lots of surprises when you're working on real-world problems.

Answer (score 2):

Just subtract the maximum value from the minimum value. This is trivial in Python. A cool way to do this is with `itemgetter`. You can find the min/max index and value at the same time if you enumerate the items in the list, but perform min/max on the original values of the list. Like so:

```
>>> import operator
>>> values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
>>> min_index, min_value = min(enumerate(values), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
>>> min_index, min_value
0, 1
>>> max_index, max_value = max(enumerate(values), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
4, 5
>>> difference = max_value - min_value
>>> difference
4
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using `max` and `min` + `enumerate`:

```
biggest_idx, biggest_value = max(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: x[1])
smallest_idx, smallest_value = min(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

e.g.:

```
>>> lst =  [1,2,3,4,5] 
>>> biggest_idx, biggest_value = max(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> smallest_idx, smallest_value = min(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> print biggest_idx, biggest_value
4 5
>>> print smallest_idx, smallest_value
0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
min_i = 0
max_i = 0
for i in xrange(len(alist)):
    if alist[i] < alist[min_i]:
        min_i = i
    if alist[i] > alist[max_i]:
        max_i = i
print "min=%d, max=%d" % (alist[min_i], alist[max_i])
print "min index=%d, max index=%d", (min_i, max_i)
print "difference=%d" % (alist[min_i] - alist[max_i])
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as ...

```
numlist=[4,1,6,3,10,8]
print('min value index : ' , numlist.index(min(numlist)))
print('max value index : ' , numlist.index(max(numlist)))
print('Max Difference : ',max(numlist)-min(numlist))
```