# Find Maximum difference between two numbers in list using Bitwise AND

Tags: c#, loops, optimization, bitwise-and

Hi all i am solving a problem that says :

> Given a set S = {1, 2, 3, ... N}. Find two integers A and B where (A < B), from set S such that the value of A&B, where '&' is bitwise AND, is the maximum possible number less than a given integer K.
>
> Sample Input1 : 5 2, (where n = 5, k = 2) => Output : 1,
>
> Sample Input2 : 8 5, (where n = 8, k = 5) => Output : 4

I wrote the code and this seems to be working fine. But I am looking for more optimized solution. I am currently using two while loops, which I am not sure could be reduced to one single while or for loop. Below is my function :

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    string[] tokens_n = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_n[0]);
    int k = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_n[1]);
    int i = 1, maxDiff = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
      int j = i + 1;
      while (j <= n)
      {
        int diff = i & j;
        if (diff < k)
        {
          if (diff > maxDiff)
          {
            maxDiff = diff;
          }
        }
        j++;
      }
      i++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(maxDiff);
}
```

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594666/python-im-trying-to-find-the-maximum-difference-between-two-elements-in-a-list) but that problem seems to be about finding maximum difference in two arbitrary numbers in a list, whereas i need to loop for all the combinations to find the Bitwise AND value and then compare it.

Comment: Code is fine.  I would use For loops instead of while loops.  For loop are easier to understand and would reduce the number of lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
int maxAnd = INT_MIN;
    for(int i = 1; i < k; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
            int currentAnd = i & j;
            if (currentAnd > maxAnd)
                maxAnd = currentAnd;
        }
    }
    cout << maxAnd << endl;
```

Comment: It runs in O(kn) time...better than O(n2)...I have posted in c++ language

Answer (score 0):

This might be not more optimized from efficiency perspective, but somewhat more readable.

```
    var list = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    var k = 2;

    var combinations = 
        from item1 in list
        from item2 in list
        where
            (item1 < item2) &&
            (item1 & item2) < k
        orderby item1 & item2 descending
        select new {item1, item2};

    Console
        .WriteLine(combinations.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution can be drastically simplified (in terms of what we check, rather than readability). So, rather than providing ways to improve the code - I can offer a new solution to the original requirement

```
void Main()
{
    var n = 2;
    var k = 2;

    //Best solution is for k - 1 (that is, B = k - 1, and then we check all possible As)
    for (var i = k - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int j;
        int index = 1;
        //The only possible A is when 
        //1. j <= n
        //2. j contains all the same bits as i since we identify that `i` is the possible solution, 
        //   and we are using bit-wise AND, we
        //So, here were looping while the number is the same as i, continually flipping bits on
        //Since we're shifting bits in, we can assume the first value != i is a solution, as we only care about j becoming too large
        while ((j = (i | index)) == i && j <= n)
            index = (index << 1) | 1;

        // If j <= n, and it contains all the bits of i, and i <= k - 1, then we have a solution
        if (j <= n)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"i = {i}, j = {j}, Solution = {i & j}");
            return;
        }
    }

    if (n < 2 || k < 1)
        Console.WriteLine("No solution");
    else
        Console.WriteLine($"i = 1, j = 2, Solution = 0");
}
```

This approach lets us solve inputs such as:

```
var n = 24827492;
var k = 2384972;
```

Almost as quickly as we can for low values.